# Datatable displacement after load from server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I got a problem with my table. After I load the json-data from the server, the new created search bar and the row are disturbing each other. The strange thing is, that this is the only site / datatable, where this is happening.

[Screenshot of the table](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150422/lespiiv7.png)

I'm using a custom theme, but the the js files are as recommended by the documentation:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"><script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.6/api/fnReloadAjax.js"><script>
```

And the code is pretty much from the demo:

```
$('#statistik').dataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "ajax": include
});
```

Do you guys have any idea what's causing this problem?

Comment: create a fiddle, we cant inspect it

Comment: seems to be a css problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue (by trial and error)! I had to simply add a parameter to the dataTable-command.

```
 $('#statistik').dataTable({
     "destroy": true,
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "ajax": include
 });
```

Anyway, thanks for your help!